# Custom link color or stylesheets

Tags: theme-development, multisite, themes, css

I'm developing av theme for my WPMU users and are wondering is there a function for choosing the colors on the links?

The same way Wordpress lets you change the background-color or header-images. Just for the link-color..

An alternative is to switch between 2 or 3 stylesheet files

Comment: do you mean you want to have one theme for all sub-sites? then you just create one theme and activate that for each subsite.... Or you just add your link colours to the CSS for the theme.

Comment: I'm making a theme and are wondering if there is a function for changing link-color in the theme trough the dashboard the same way you can change background-color, header-image etc

Comment: [off-topic] Are you still using WPMU or is it already a Multisite?

Comment: Its a working theme thats on a multisite system right now. I wanna add the possibility to change the linkcolor trough the new customize menu in WP

Answer (score 0):

In answer (im not a theme developer) so please improve this answer

In WordPress 3.4 the Theme Customiser was introduced for example in Twenty Eleven theme you have a colour wheel.

Have a look at Otto's write up on how to leverage Theme Customiser http://ottopress.com/2012/how-to-leverage-the-theme-customizer-in-your-own-themes/

Comment: it just shows the function... but not how to add it to your own theme

Comment: I think then you'll find you need to look at how to create an options page for your theme like this tut http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-better-wordpress-options-panel/

Comment: great tutorial, but I need it to be in the standard wordpress customize menu.

Comment: Perhaps follow the tutorial and search the Wordpress codex ... Also I think you mean Appearance menu.

Comment: yes, you are right, its the appearance menu. But cant fint it in the codex... thats why I tried here

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus and you'll want add theme page